# Stripe - Keep on getting invalid_request_error response

Tags: android, api, react-native, stripe-payments

I am using stripe integration on react native. I followed the instruction on this [URL](https://github.com/llanox/react-native-stripe-wrapper/)

I can send request to Stripe but I am getting error response all the time.

```
response {
"error": {
"type": "invalid_request_error",
"message": "Invalid API Key provided: \"[****** ********fer]\". 
This key contains at least one space. Please delete the spaces and try again. If you have any questions, we can help at https://support.stripe.com/."
}
}
```

But I double checked there isn't any space in the secret key but no luck.

Any idea, what I am missing?

Note: My stripe account is in test mode and I am using the test secret key.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your code, somewhere is using the wrong key as it has a space in it. Based on the error message, it's also explicitly shown where your key currently looks like this: `[****** ********fer]`.

If you search your codebase for a word that ends with `fer` you will find a place where you haven't put the right API key and instead copy pasted something else.